# how to query a database using wpf application and get output like SQL Management Studio?

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqlcmd

I have one store procedure in my database, it makes many things and print results when i run it on sqlserver management studio (ssms), for example:

exporting table abc...
exporting table def...
deleting table temp...

My program has to run the store procedure and show the output anywhere (maybe creating a log file), such as ssms does (it shows output in the messages tab). I have to show exactly the same ssms shows. How can I do this?? sqlcmd, ado.net?? I see this question

[How to run sql from a .net application against sqlserver and get output like with SQL Management Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675396/how-to-run-sql-from-a-net-application-against-sqlserver-and-get-output-like-with)

but, answer is not clear... Help!!

Comment: Hi, search here in SO, there were other questions and answers pointing to the right direction (not the one you mentioned above which does not help really)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to capture warning and information messages, you will want to create a SqlInfoMessageEventHandler delegate to handle the SqlConnection.InfoMessage event.  See references below for details.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlinfomessageeventhandler.aspx

Comment: this was the answer I was looking for but couldn't find it faster than you Kenny :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I called sqlcmd from my app with -o, by this way i get a file with the same output that ssms generates, and can read it and show it in my app.

Comment: As a caveat: SQL Server Management Studio uses the Microsoft .NET Framework SqlClient for execution in regular and SQLCMD mode in Query Editor. When sqlcmd is run from the command line, sqlcmd uses the OLE DB provider. Because different default options may apply, you might see different behavior when you execute the same query in SQL Server Management Studio in SQLCMD Mode and in the sqlcmd utility.

Comment: sqlcmd is done without ado.net, as you've posted.  Not sure if that is easier or not.  You are calling out to an external process. Just depends on your scenario.